# svg can't change color when requiring svg in js

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I want to change the color of SVG.  in my js file, I include it first such as:

```
let VrmSvg = require('@src/assets/images/vrm.svg');
```

Then, I try to do something such as:

```
 let _new_svg = VrmSvg.replace("rgb(255,255,255)", ((index) >= colors.length) ? "%23fff" : colors[(index)].replace("#","%23"));
```

Don't pay attention to my variables.

Now, this is not working. I will tell you when It was working. Before me, other developer would try to make an http api call to get that svg and in response, he was doing the same code as me (replace function). So I think difference is requiring it vs making http api call for it.

In case you need, I am also posting my svg content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?><!-- Generator: Gravit.io -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="isolation:isolate" viewBox="0 0 40 40" width="40" height="40">

    <defs>
        <clipPath id="_clipPath_bV3rFtMJT2YVUd3w3HxRFhJgB50imkCE">
            <rect width="40" height="40"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g clip-path="url(#_clipPath_bV3rFtMJT2YVUd3w3HxRFhJgB50imkCE)">
        <mask id="_mask_C4LsnjmjxRPYTQbZR4sq3rRWgds6obLw">
            <path d=" M 31.299 12.597 C 31.299 6.192 26.107 1 19.703 1 C 14.836 1 10.669 3.998 8.949 8.247 C 8.405 9.59 8.106 11.059 8.106 12.597 C 8.106 14.142 8.414 15.613 8.962 16.961 L 8.955 16.963 L 8.99 17.038 C 9.066 17.219 9.154 17.393 9.238 17.569 L 19.69 40 L 19.691 40 L 19.715 40 L 19.716 40 L 30.184 17.533 C 30.262 17.37 30.343 17.21 30.412 17.043 L 30.45 16.963 L 30.442 16.96 C 30.991 15.613 31.299 14.141 31.299 12.597 Z " 
                  fill="white" 
                  stroke="none"/>
        </mask>
        <path d=" M 31.299 12.597 C 31.299 6.192 26.107 1 19.703 1 C 14.836 1 10.669 3.998 8.949 8.247 C 8.405 9.59 8.106 11.059 8.106 12.597 C 8.106 14.142 8.414 15.613 8.962 16.961 L 8.955 16.963 L 8.99 17.038 C 9.066 17.219 9.154 17.393 9.238 17.569 L 19.69 40 L 19.691 40 L 19.715 40 L 19.716 40 L 30.184 17.533 C 30.262 17.37 30.343 17.21 30.412 17.043 L 30.45 16.963 L 30.442 16.96 C 30.991 15.613 31.299 14.141 31.299 12.597 Z " 
              fill="rgb(255,255,255)" 
              mask="url(#_mask_C4LsnjmjxRPYTQbZR4sq3rRWgds6obLw)" 
              vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" stroke-width="4" 
              stroke="rgb(55,55,55)" 
              stroke-linejoin="miter" 
              stroke-linecap="butt"
              stroke-miterlimit="4"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you are using a bundler like webpack or not but requiring an svg won't usually return the svg as a string value.

You could do something like this instead:

Set up a 'vrm.js' file

and within that have...

```
modulde.exports = {
  svg: "<svg>...SVG code goes here...</svg>"
}
```

then require it in your code via the following...

```
let VrmSvg = require('...path to new js file').svg;
```